# What's the proper way of setting environment variable in Netlify functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, lambda, gatsby, netlify

What's the proper way of setting environment variables in netlify? I would like to be able to set different values for the variables depending on the environment.

Pseudo code:

```
let host;
if (process.env.GATSBY_CUSTOM_CONTEXT === 'production') {
    host = process.env.PRODUCTION_HOST
} else if (process.env.GATSBY_CUSTOM_CONTEXT === 'development') {
    host = process.env.DEVELOPMENT_HOST
}
```

I have tried passing env variable thru CLI, like `GATSBY_CUSTOM_CONTEXT=production gatsby build` and I also tried using same command with `cross-env`.

My other attempt used `netlify.toml`:

```
[build]
  base = "/"
  publish = "public"
  command = "yarn build"
  functions = "src/functions"

[context.production]
  [context.production.environment]
    GATSBY_CUSTOM_CONTEXT = "production"
```

All of these options worked with `netlify dev` locally, but in production `GATSBY_CUSTOM_CONTEXT` is always `undefined`.

Comment: What OS are you building on?

Comment: Ubuntu Xenial 16.04

Comment: Are you trying to read these env variables client side or server side?

Comment: Server side. I’m working with netlify functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you can't resolve the environment variables in your Netlify functions is because **as of the time of your question,** Netlify does not transfer the environment variables from the `netlify.toml` file.

You must put them into the admin panel in your site settings in the `app.netlify.com` dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, what you're looking to doesn't seem to be currently supported.  Though they provide an alternative approach.

I found this snippet on their docs:

> CALLING ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES
>
> Using environment variables directly as
> values ($VARIABLENAME) in your netlify.toml file is not supported.
> However, the following workflow can be used to substitute values in
> the file with environment variable values, assuming you are only
> trying to change headers or redirects. The rest of the file is read
> BEFORE your build — but those sections are read AFTER the build
> process.
>
> 1. Add a placeholder like HEADER_PLACEHOLDER somewhere in the netlify.toml redirects or headers sections.
> 2. Create an environment variable, for example PROD_API_LOCATION, with the desired value. You can create environment variables in the
>    toml file or in our UI. You might use the latter to keep sensitive
>    values out of your repository.
> 3. Prepend a replacement command to your build command. Here’s an example for a site using yarn build to build: sed -i
>    s/HEADER_PLACEHOLDER/${PROD_API_LOCATION}/g netlify.toml && yarn build

Taken from here: https://www.netlify.com/docs/netlify-toml-reference/